# How to get FB like count for each post while pulling the feed via Open Graph API?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am trying to get all the posts for a page by using

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed

And it works like a charm. I can get all the info for each post except the like count.

The feed does return "likes" for each post, but it shows the like info for the first 25 likes. I cannot know the like count of a post.

The closest solution I found on the net is to set "summary=1" when requesting info of a post, e.g.

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=1

This will return a summary field that shows the like count of this post, which is exactly what I need.

However, if this is the only way to solve the problem, I have to make additional network request for each post just for getting the like count. I could originally finish the job with only ONE network request, but now I have make 1+N times (number of posts in the page feed) of network requests.

I think I must be missing something. FB must have some way to get the like count embedded in the feed info. Just like the FB app or website, all posts show their like counts immediately, there is no way to make additional N times of network requests in order to get the like count for each post.

Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I searched the net again and tried a few things,

The like count is actually there if the access token is obtained via a logged in user.

I can't get the like count because there is no user logged in. I don't know why there is such a difference...

Anyway I can still get the like count if I change some configuration? (such as app settings?)

Comment: Facebook's October 5, 2013 Breaking changes suggest that they are not going to give likes count in feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found there is a way to get the like/comment counts for each post while pulling the feed without making further network requests:

```
/url/feed?fields=likes.summary(1).limit(0)
```

Isn't it great?